# getting error : Cannot run EXGL in a simulator

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-native, expo

I am working on expo in react native, when i run my code in android simulator, it is giving me error : Cannot run EXGL in a simulator, can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ? here is my full code of it

```
class Screenone extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    alert("testing");  
  }

  onContextCreate = ({ gl, scale: pixelRatio, width, height }) => {
    AR.setPlaneDetection(AR.PlaneDetectionTypes.Horizontal);

    this.renderer = new ExpoTHREE.Renderer({
      gl,
      pixelRatio,
      width,
      height,
    });

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.background = new ThreeAR.BackgroundTexture(this.renderer);
    this.camera = new ThreeAR.Camera(width, height, 0.01, 1000);
  };

  onResize = ({ x, y, scale, width, height }) => {
    this.camera.aspect = width / height;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(scale);
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
  };

  onRender = () => {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <GraphicsView
        style={{ flex: 2 }}
        onContextCreate={this.onContextCreate}
        onRender={this.onRender}
        onResize={this.onResize}
        isArEnabled
        isArRunningStateEnabled
        isArCameraStateEnabled
        arTrackingConfiguration={AR.TrackingConfigurations.World}
      />
    );
  }
}
```